# What do people mean when they put a subscript in a partial derivative

Tags: derivatives, notation, partial-derivative, physics

One definition of temperature I have seen is

$$T= \left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right)_N.$$

While $E, S, N$ each has clear meaning (internal energy, entropy, number of particles), I don't know how to interpret the subscript $N$.

Do I take an average among all particles or is there any other meaning?

Answer (score 3):

The subscript $N$ on the partial derivative means that $N$ is held constant.

Comment: search for statistical mechanics on [this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) page